# Custom Product Export description space

Tags: magento-1.9, csv

I export Custom csv to the product

```
public function exportmeAction(){
      try{

    $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
            $products->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids');
            $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//optional for only enabled products
            $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
            ->joinField('qty',
                             'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                             'qty',
                             'product_id=entity_id',
                             '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                             'left');
    $content = "Product Id,Product Name,Product Sku,Product Url,Product Image Url,Category Ids,Description,Product Qty,Special Price, Price\n";
    foreach ($products as $product){
        $content .= $product->getId() . ",";            
        $content .= $product->getName() . ",";
        $content .= $product->getSku() . ",";
        $content .= $product->getProductUrl() . ",";
        $content .= (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image') . ",";
        $content .= implode('|', $product->getCategoryIds()). ",";//change the category separator if needed
        $content .= strip_tags($product->getDescription()) . ",";
        $content .= (int)$product->getQty() . ",";
        $content .= (int)$product->getFinalPrice() . ",";
        $content .= (int)$product->getPrice() . ",";
        $content .= "\n";
        }

    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error Message: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
      Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess("Done");
     $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('export.csv', $content, 'text/csv');
   }
```

My problem is Description there som space 
 tag's is there due to that description take one one cell how i fix that

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try below code for that

```
$description =  $product->getDescription()
$content .= '"'.$description.'"'. ",";
```

try and let me know

Comment: Same only ........

Comment: @Kothari check updated one

Comment: You are always welcome @Kothari :)